# Submit Message Check Script/Program

Tags: version-control, mercurial, qt-creator

I want to setup my IDE(qt creator) with version control(mercurial).On the options page,i am asked to provide the "Submit message check script".Does this script come with the TortoiseHG that i am using or is it part of the qt creator ide?.

Answer (score 0):

Mercurial on Qtcreator started to work after restarting the computer. When installing TortoiseSVN, i do recall having to restart the computer, i think the same applies for TortoiseHG.

Answer (score 0):

No submit message check script is provided, far as I know, and it is safe to leave this field blank.

The submit message check script is not required, unless you want to make a script that will check your submit messages for errors, and cancel the commit if they are not compliant with your in-house standards.

http://doc.qt.digia.com/qtcreator-2.1/creator-version-control.html#setting-up-common-options describes it thus:
"Submit message check script is a script or program that can be used to perform checks on the submit message before submitting. The submit message is passed in as the script's first parameter. If there is an error, the script should output a message on standard error and return a non-zero exit code."